# Using a WHERE colname NOT LIKE (select * from otherTable)

Tags: mysql, subquery, string-searching, substring

So in essence what im trying to do is this:

Given `TBL1` (around 8,000 rows)

| letters |
| --- |
| abababa |
| bcbcbcb |
| cdcdcdc |

and `TBL2` (around 2,000 rows)

| letters |
| --- |
| ab |
| bc |

I want to write a query to find every row in `TBL1` that does not contain atleast one of the substrings in `TBL2`

It has to be using a subquery because the actual code (cant post here bc its sensitive information) is a pretty complex query with a couple of concatenations and trims etc.

Im trying to do this roughly

```
SELECT * FROM TBL1 WHERE TBL1.letters NOT LIKE '%'|| (SELECT letters FROM TBL2) ||'%'
```

My intention is to get the following output returned:

| letters |
| --- |
| cdcdcdc |

As the last row does not contain 'ab' or 'bc'.

to get an idea what my code looks like i will enclose with with out any identifying information.

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  tbl1
WHERE
  tbl1.col1 NOT LIKE '%' ||(
    SELECT
      LTRIM(
        RTRIM(
          CONCAT(
            REPLACE(
              tbl2.col1,
              CONCAT(tbl2.col2, tbl2.col3),
              ""
            ),
            " ",
            tbl2.col2,
            " ",
            tbl2.col3
          )
        )
      )
    FROM
      tbl2
  ) || '%'
```

Comment: Mr.Smith something like 10,000 rows

Comment: TBL1 around 8000 and TBL2 around 2000

Comment: My gut says that it will take 16,000,000 tests.  Do you have a time constraint?  And/or, will the size of the tables grow?

Comment: *Im trying to do this roughly* Your logic is incorrect. The subquery returns a rowset, not a scalar (single) value which will cause an error.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to achieve this. try using the **NOT LIKE** operator in combination with a subquery that concatenates all the letters from TBL2 into a single string and checks if that string is not present in each row of TBL1

Try this

```
SELECT *
FROM TBL1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM TBL2
  WHERE TBL1.letters LIKE '%' || TBL2.letters || '%'
)
```

Comment: But why. You could improve your answer by explaining.

Comment: You are not using `NOT LIKE` though.

Answer (score 1):

An option could be to create an auxiliary table to index suffixes of the strings from the table `TBL1`. The tables could look as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL1`
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `letters` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);
```

`TBL1`

| id | letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abababa |
| 2 | bcbcbcb |
| 3 | cdcdcdc |

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL2`
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `letters` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `tbl2_letters_uindex` UNIQUE (`letters`)
);
```

`TBL2`

| id | letters |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | ab |
| 2 | bc |

```
CREATE TABLE `TBL1SUFFIX`
(
    `id` INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `suffix`  VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    `tbl1_id` INT NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `tbl1suffix_suffix_tbl1_id_uindex`
        UNIQUE (`suffix`, `tbl1_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `tbl1suffix_tbl1_fk`
        FOREIGN KEY (`tbl1_id`) REFERENCES `TBL1` (`id`)
            ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

For each word in the table, `TBL1` their suffixes are added to the suffix table:

| id | suffix | tbl1_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abababa | 1 |
| 2 | bababa | 1 |
| 3 | bcbcbcb | 2 |
| 4 | cbcbcb | 2 |
| 5 | cdcdcdc | 3 |
| 6 | dcdcdc | 3 |

Here, all suffixes of, for example, `abababa` are

```
abababa
bababa
ababa
baba
aba
ba
a
```

However, I excluded the ones that are suffixes of other suffixes.

Given that the suffixes are indexed, if we look up words that contain, for example, `cb`, the search would be performed on the index of suffixes by starting characters, using pattern matching `LIKE 'cb%'` instead of `LIKE '%cb%'`, and return the suffix `cbcbcb`:

| id | suffix | tbl1_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | cbcbcb | 2 |

Excluding the words in the table `TBL1` that are not equal to the received `tbl1_id`, we get the words that don't contain `cb`.

The query, in this case, could be:

```
SELECT
    `TBL1`.`letters`
FROM
    `TBL1`
    LEFT JOIN (
        SELECT
            `TBL1SUFFIX`.`tbl1_id`
        FROM
            `TBL1SUFFIX`
            LEFT JOIN `TBL2`
                ON `TBL1SUFFIX`.`suffix` LIKE CONCAT(`TBL2`.`letters`, '%')
        WHERE
            `TBL2`.`id` IS NOT NULL
    ) `suffix`
        ON `TBL1`.`id` = `suffix`.`tbl1_id`
WHERE
    `suffix`.`tbl1_id` IS NULL;
```

or:

```
SELECT
    `TBL1`.`letters`
FROM
    `TBL1`
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT
            1
        FROM
            `TBL1SUFFIX`
        WHERE
            EXISTS(
                SELECT 1
                FROM
                    `TBL2`
                WHERE
                    `TBL1SUFFIX`.`suffix` LIKE CONCAT(`TBL2`.`letters`, '%')
                    AND `TBL1`.`id` = `TBL1SUFFIX`.`tbl1_id`
            )
    );
```